# Python Get dict value only, without key from Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, pymysql

In Python3, I take value from `Mysql` by dict. (using `pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor`)

However, I writing the function get point and display to `html`(Flask), it show the dict key & dict

Here is my code

```
staffCrt['B'] = repo.countstaff(month['bonus'], ">", line[0])
staffCrt['S'] = repo.countstaff(month['bonus'], "<", line[0])   
staffList.append(staffCrt)
```

The SQL in countstaff()

```
sql = "SELECT count(point) from matches where month = '12'"
self.cursor.execute(sql)
return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

The function return the dict:

```
{'count(point)': 15}
```

I have try to use

```
staffCrt['B'].values()
```

but it return 
    dict_values([15])

How can i get the value "15" only?

Comment: could you edit your question printing out what staffCrt is? Also, is staffCrt a dictionary?

Comment: First of all, take a look at [mcve] on how to provide code that works. The code you've given is very hard to understand.... Second, you can do `staffCrt['B']['count(point)']`.

Comment: staffCrt is a dict. @SBylemans Thank you for your comments ,i will post the code better & clear on next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Access a certain value from a dict :**

Basically, `d[key] = value`

**dict_values :**

If you call `d.values()` on a dict `d`, that will return a `dict_values` object that you should transform in `list` if you want to access its data. `list(d.values())`

**Your problem :**

> The function return the dict:
>   {'count(point)': 15}

Then, if `output` is the return of the function :

```
output['count(point)']
```

will return `15`

**With your edit :**

Actually `output = staffCrt['B']` so,

```
staffCrt['B']['count(point)'] = 15
```

Comment: Thank you it work fine! i was try staffCrt['B'][staffCrt['B'].keys()] but no luck, thank you for your solution!